# JSON Parsing taking too much time - Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a JSON file `airports.json` which contains 5720 objects, I want to parse the file in Java into Objects Airport.
The code below is how I parse it, the problem is, it is taking too much time to completely parse all the file, about 1 min and 50 sec.

```
    ArrayList<Airport> arrayAirports = new ArrayList<>();
    String json_response = loadJSONFromAsset();
    try {
        JSONObject airports = new JSONObject(json_response.trim());

        Log.d("Length Array 0", String.valueOf(airports.names().length()));
        Log.d("Length Array 1", String.valueOf(arrayAirports.size()));
        for(int i = 0; i<airports.names().length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonAirport = airports.getJSONObject(airports.names().getString(i));
                Airport newAirport = new Airport();
                newAirport.name = jsonAirport.getString("name");
                newAirport.city = jsonAirport.getString("city");
                newAirport.country = jsonAirport.getString("country");
                newAirport.latitude = jsonAirport.getString("latitude");
                newAirport.longitude = jsonAirport.getString("longitude");
                newAirport.altitude = jsonAirport.getString("altitude");
                newAirport.iata = jsonAirport.getString("iata");
                newAirport.icao = jsonAirport.getString("icao");
                newAirport.timeZone = jsonAirport.getString("timezone");
                newAirport.dst = jsonAirport.getString("dst");
                arrayAirports.add(newAirport);
        }



    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("Length Array 2", String.valueOf(arrayAirports.size()));
```

Is there a way to parse it quicklier.
By the way my friend is parsing it with no time at all using Objective C.

[Link to JSON file](https://github.com/ram-nadella/airport-codes/blob/master/airports.json)

Comment: Try it with third party libraries instead of doing it manually https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I am trying to use it right now but I didn't get how to loop throught the JSON file and add a Airport object each time

Comment: JSONObject.names() in every iteration ... twice?

Comment: That's the only way that I could think about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it matters for performance, but you shouldn't call `names()` repeatedly. Assign to variable before loop, then use it.

```
JSONArray names = airports.names();
Log.d("Length Array 0", String.valueOf(names.length()));
Log.d("Length Array 1", String.valueOf(arrayAirports.size()));
for(int i = 0; i<names.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonAirport = airports.getJSONObject(names.getString(i));
    // code
}
```

**Better yet, use `length()` and `keys()`:**

```
Log.d("Length Array 0", String.valueOf(airports.length()));
Log.d("Length Array 1", String.valueOf(arrayAirports.size()));
for (Iterator<String> nameIter = airports.keys(); nameIter.hasNext(); ){
    String name = nameIter.next();
    JSONObject jsonAirport = airports.getJSONObject(name);
    // code
}
```

Comment: *Don't know if it matters for performance* ... `public JSONArray names() {
         JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
         Iterator keys = this.keys();
         while (keys.hasNext()) {
             ja.put(keys.next());
         }
         return ja.length() == 0 ? null : ja;
 }` <= of course it does ... it creates JSONArray with size of the `keys()` size ...  iterate `keys()` and put its item to this array ... even only releasing this JSONArray (and gc) would take some time

Comment: @Selvin Even worse, it returns `null` if object is empty, so that is a very dangerous method to use, given that it may cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks that did the job for me without changing too much of my code

Comment: @IlhemNemri Note that because of the NPE danger, you should use `keys()`, not `names()`, and that is also better for performance, because it doesn't have to copy the names into an array first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) instead and measure the speed with it. While it is possible possible that just reading the file could take a long time, a whole minute seems pretty bad.

Since you mentioned you don't know how to use GSON, [here's a tutorial I wrote for a student on how to use GSON](http://toomanytutorials.blogspot.com/2016/02/deserialize-json-data-returned-from.html). It assume you're getting the file from a network call though, so you need to apply it to use your local JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting a (I guess?) large JSON data file into a JSONObject directly.

In this case it would be recommended to use a token based reader, such as [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

Pasted directly from the docs:

```
public List readJsonStream(InputStream in ) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader( in , "UTF-8"));
    try {
        return readMessagesArray(reader);
        finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public List readMessagesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        List messages = new ArrayList();

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            messages.add(readMessage(reader));
        }
        reader.endArray();
        return messages;
    }

    public Message readMessage(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        long id = -1;
        String text = null;
        User user = null;
        List geo = null;

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("id")) {
                id = reader.nextLong();
            } else if (name.equals("text")) {
                text = reader.nextString();
            } else if (name.equals("geo") && reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                geo = readDoublesArray(reader);
            } else if (name.equals("user")) {
                user = readUser(reader);
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        return new Message(id, text, user, geo);
    }

    public List readDoublesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        List doubles = new ArrayList();

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            doubles.add(reader.nextDouble());
        }
        reader.endArray();
        return doubles;
    }

    public User readUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        String username = null;
        int followersCount = -1;

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("name")) {
                username = reader.nextString();
            } else if (name.equals("followers_count")) {
                followersCount = reader.nextInt();
            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();
        return new User(username, followersCount);
    }
}
```